# Extend NTFS partition on dual boot

Tags: linux-mint, partition, ntfs, gparted

I have Linux Mint and Windows 10 on the laptop I work with, Windows 10 partition due to Microsoft continuous updating the system is now full and I'd like to extend it. I read I have to run linux live on a stick and work on gparted, the problem is the unallocated space is not close to the partition I want to extend.

How can i fix this? Thanks in advance

[image: Gparted on linux mint]

Comment: There's really no fix for that. You need the unallocated space to be next to (meaning right after) the partition you want to extend. Yet you have an extended partition there. I suppose you can delete the extended partition, allocate some space to Windows, and then reinstall Linux, or restore from backup; which is effectively like moving the unallocated space. But what will you do when Windows needs more space later? Perhaps a more flexible option is to run the "secondary os" in a virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, I'll try deleting the partition and restore, is there a simple way to restore from backup? I've always reinstalled from scratch.

Comment: A simple way? No. With *significant* Linux experience it's possible to backup and restore Linux systems quite easily, as long as you think it through and plan it out. Lacking such experience, a fresh install is the best way to go.